# How to calculate p-values from cross-correlation function in R

Tags: r, time-series, p-value, cross-correlation

I calculated a cross-correlation of two time series using `ccf()` in R. I know how to derive the confidence limits as:

```
ccf1 <- ccf(x=x,y=y,lag.max=5,na.action=na.pass, plot=F)
upperCI <- qnorm((1+0.95)/2)/sqrt(ccf1$n.used)
lowerCI <- -qnorm((1+0.95)/2)/sqrt(ccf1$n.used)
```

But what I really need is the p-value of the maximum correlation.

```
ind.max <- which(abs(ccf1$acf[1:11])==max(abs(ccf1$acf[1:11])))
max.cor <- ccf1$acf[ind.max]
lag.opt <- ccf1$lag[ind.max]
```

How do I calculate this p-value? I have searched high and low but can't find a good answer anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting p-value is straightforward.

Under Null Hypothesis that the correlation is 0, it is normally distributed:

```
Z ~ N(0, 1/sqrt(ccf1$n.used))
```

So for your observed maximum correlation `max.cor`, its p-value is just the probability `Pr(Z > |max.cor|)`, which can be computed by:

```
2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(max.cor), mean = 0, sd = 1/sqrt(ccf1$n.used)))
```

---

**Follow-up**

> Is it really that simple? The `ccf` is computing many correlations at once!

Are you saying that `ccf` is computing correlations at different lags? Well, provided you have large number of observations `N`, the standard deviation of ACF at each lag is the same: `1/sqrt(N)`. That is why the confidence interval are two horizontal lines.

Comment: It is really that simple?  I was thinking that there had to me some catch because the ccf is computing many correlations at once?